# lwjgl appearing floor

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I got an idea for a 3d game I am making in lwjgl.
Basically, I would want tiles appearing when you fly close to a certain height(forming some kind of platform around you), and each tile would dissapear individually after a random time.

I have no idea how to start programming this, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm new here as well. You'll probably get answers faster if you provide a little more detail in your question (where would the tiles form, cubes or planes, etc.) For my explanation I'm going to assume you have a pretty good understanding of Java.

First, get the basics down. Learn how to draw quads, colors, and move the camera around. There are some really great tutorials here: http://www.youtube.com/user/TheCodingUniverse/videos?view=0, try checking them out.

For your tiles, one thing you could do is make a few Vectors (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) for the tile's X positions, Y positions, and Z positions. Create a function that sorts through these Vectors and draws quads (tiles) at their positions. Also figure out how to have the player land on the tiles, and jump around on them. Once the player gets close to the specified height, start adding tiles (using your Vectors holding their positions) at the player's position plus a random amount. Then, every frame, go through all the elements in the Vectors (at the same time) and make it so that there is a small chance (`if(Math.random()>0.995)`) that the program will remove the X, Y, and Z elements for that tile.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your answer!
I will definitely give this a go :)